# Zsh oneliner to Extract part of string until and including token

Tags: zsh

I need a solution in zsh

I have a string like `http://xxx.abc.mp3?yyy:mno`. Is there a one-liner in zsh that can extract the string until `mp3`, that `http://xxx.abc.mp3`? I can do this in bash, but I needed a way to do it in zsh.

Comment: Please edit to show your work. Currently, this is off-topic (too broad) as it's just a requirement and a request for the Community to solve it. You already mentioned having a bash solution - at a minimum, you can show that, along with what you tried in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you did it in `bash`, but the same substitution works with both shells:

```sh
str='http://xxx.abc.mp3?yyy:mno'
printf "%s\n" "${str/%\?*}"
```

Removes the text that matches a question mark and 0 or more characters until the end of the string.